# How to call Spinner from property loadingIndicator in Nuxt.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to show Spinner from property loadingIndicator in Nuxt.Js?

this code, for call progressbar when req API: 
**this.$root.$loading.start()** https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading

---

but.. how to call this property?
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator

Comment: The progressbar is automatically run between 2 Nuxt routes transition. If the target route has a call API on init (from `asyncData()` method), the progressbar will wait the end. But you want run the progressbar manually on a call API, right?

Comment: yes right sir..